# How to convert x y coordinates to OSM using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I would like to convert them to OSM file format (.osm).

Comment: I have the Parking Regulation Data shapefile of NY.
Add into QGIS using "Add vector layer", then set project CRS to EPSG:3857.
To export:
QGIS->Vectorial->OpenStreetMap->Download data
in "from layer" point to the layer added then Ok to generate the  osm file.
The generated file the first time had a nodes data pointing only to the street's info (name,...) but not the shapefile info (street regolations).
Only the first time, after that the osm file generated is empty.

Answer (score 6):

There is **NO** way to export data to .osm format in QGIS.

The menu point you used is just to **download** OSM raw data, and export it to a spatialite database.

Alternatively, you can save to GPX format (waypoints and tracks) in EPSG:4326, and load the file in the JOSM editor. It can convert GPX layers to OSM format. But take care for existing data before uploading to the OSM server.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your layer in qgis you can save it as .shp file using epsg:4326, then you can open it with JOSM (you need OpenData plugin).

Take a look at formats provided by OpenData - there is few more of them than .shp which could be not best idea when you have long column names.